# Use JSON variable as public variable?

Tags: jquery, json, flickr

I'm loading my Flickr set into my website like so:

```
$(window).load(function() {
var apiKey = 'xxx';
var userId = '8378546@N08';

$.getJSON('http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?format=json&method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&photoset_id=' + photoset_id + '&per_page=1000' + '&page=1' + '&api_key=' + apiKey + '&user_id=' + userId + '&jsoncallback=?', function(data) {
    $.each(data.photoset.photo, function(i, flickrPhoto){
        var basePhotoURL = 'http://farm' + flickrPhoto.farm + '.static.flickr.com/'
        + flickrPhoto.server + '/' + flickrPhoto.id + '_' + flickrPhoto.secret + "_z.jpg";  

        var fullPhotoURL = 'http://farm' + flickrPhoto.farm + '.static.flickr.com/'
        + flickrPhoto.server + '/' + flickrPhoto.id + '_' + flickrPhoto.secret + "_l.jpg";          

        /*var FlickrLink = "http://www.flickr.com/photos/" + data.photoset.owner + "/" + flickrPhoto.id + "/";*/
        $("<img/>").attr("src", basePhotoURL).appendTo("#photographs").wrap(("<div class='item'></div>"))

    });

    **$("<a href='#' class='zoom'/>").appendTo(".item");**
    **$("<a href='#' class='flickr'/>").appendTo(".item");**

    $("#photographs").gridalicious({
        gutter: 2,
        animate: true,
        effect: 'fadeInOnAppear',
        width: 320,
        complete: onComplete()
    });

    function onComplete(){
        $("#loader").delay(20000).fadeOut("slow");
        $(".item").hover(function(){
            $(".zoom, .flickr", this).stop(true,true).fadeIn(300);
        }, function () {
            $(".zoom, .flickr", this).stop(true,true).fadeOut(300);
        });
    }
});
});
```

The .zoom & .flickr divs are appended to the .item div (which contains the picture). I need both var **fullPhotoURL** and var **FlickrLink** since i want to use them in the highlighted (with stars) anchors in the code. When i do this, i get an error that both var **fullPhotoURL** and var **FlickrLink** cannot be found.

How should i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your variables outside the $.each block:

```
$.getJSON('http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?format=json&method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&photoset_id=' + photoset_id + '&per_page=1000' + '&page=1' + '&api_key=' + apiKey + '&user_id=' + userId + '&jsoncallback=?', function(data) {

    var fullPhotoURL, FlickrLink;

    $.each(data.photoset.photo, function(i, flickrPhoto){
        var basePhotoURL = 'http://farm' + flickrPhoto.farm + '.static.flickr.com/'
        + flickrPhoto.server + '/' + flickrPhoto.id + '_' + flickrPhoto.secret + "_z.jpg";  

        fullPhotoURL = 'http://farm' + flickrPhoto.farm + '.static.flickr.com/'
        + flickrPhoto.server + '/' + flickrPhoto.id + '_' + flickrPhoto.secret + "_l.jpg";          

        /*FlickrLink = "http://www.flickr.com/photos/" + data.photoset.owner + "/" + flickrPhoto.id + "/";*/
    $("<img/>").attr("src", basePhotoURL).appendTo("#photographs").wrap(("<div class='item'></div>"))

   });

   $("<a href='#' class='zoom'/>").appendTo(".item");
```

Comment: Then i receive 'undefined' on the URL. $("<a href='" + fullPhotoURL + "' class='zoom'/>").appendTo(".item");

Comment: That is because it is asyncronuous. You need to $("<a href='#' class='zoom'/>").appendTo(".item"); inside your getJSON clause

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It is in the getJson block.

Comment: Try to move the declaration between $.getJSON and $.each as shown above.

Comment: Yes, it already is in the JSON scope. When i put in the each function, then it works, but of course it generates an url for all photos inside that one .item, which crashes my browser..

edit: @asgoth: still 'undefined'.

Answer (score 0):

To define a global variable in Javascript, you need to skip the `var` declaration term.

`var` "means" lacal variable

Start by assign a default value to your variables :

```
fullPhotoURL = null;
FlickrLink = null; //Avoid first upcase char to define variable
```

Then these variables will be available in all your functions

Comment: Thanks for the tip about first uppercase char. This works, but now i get 'undefined' for the url.. See below.